# Can Azure Devops Pipeline start script on VM (vis ssh) and continue to next task?

Tags: batch-file, ssh, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

from Azure Devops pipeline I am connecting via SSH to run a bat file on the VM:

```
  - task: SSH@0
    inputs:
      sshEndpoint: 'qam2'
      runOptions: 'commands'
      commands: 'path-to-bat-file'
      readyTimeout: '20000'
```

Now I do not want the pipelien to wait for the script to finish -> I will like to move on to the next task.
Can this be done?

I tried with

```
    timeoutInMinutes: 1
    continueOnError: true
```

But this killed the scipt.

The bat file:

```
start C:\Documents\QA_Test\Listener.lnk
start /wait C:\mainapp.exe  /SILENT 
waitfor SomethingThatIsNeverHappening /t 5 >nul 2>&1
pytest C:\test_recipeFile.py --csv C:\result.csv --csv-columns function,status,message
taskkill /f /im MainApp.exe     
taskkill /f /im WinAppDriver.exe
```

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a mechanism to bypass the execution of the task but you could use jobs for this reason. Jobs can run independent from each other considering that you can have parallelism on your setup (Microsoft hosted, or self hosted).

You could add a stage and two jobs inside that stage. On the first job you will include the bat running task that you created. In the other job you could include as many task as you want and they will run regardless of the bat run.

```
stages:
- stage: stage1
  displayName: display name for your stage
  jobs:
  - job: job1
    displayName: display name for job1
    steps:
    - script: echo job1.task1
      displayName: running job1.task1  
  - job: job2
    displayName: display name for job2
    steps:
    - script: echo job2.task1
      displayName: running job2.task1
```